# Fine Uploader post to S3 returns response code 0

Tags: fine-uploader

A customer with OSX Mountain Lion can't upload.  Issue is present in both Safari and Firefox.  I was able to get in remotely and grab some logs.  Here is the console output:

```
[13:02:17.497] [FineUploader 3.8.2] Submitting S3 signature request for 0
[13:02:17.497] [FineUploader 3.8.2] Sending POST request for 0
[13:02:17.568] POST http://removed/signature [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 462ms]
[13:02:18.034] OPTIONS http://mybucket.removed/ [0ms]
[13:02:17.985] no element found @ http://removed/the/url/of/the/uploader
[13:02:17.979] [FineUploader 3.8.2] Sending upload request for 0
[13:02:17.984] [FineUploader 3.8.2] Received response status 0 with body: 
[13:02:17.986] [FineUploader 3.8.2] Waiting 5 seconds before retrying file.jpg...
```

The signature part seems to go fine.  The post to Amazon just doesn't return anything.  Is this a CORS issue?  They claim to not be running any virus or security program on their computer. The computer is their own and is on their home network.

Here is the CORS configuration on S3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>removed</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>removed</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>removed</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>removed</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>removed</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Comment: It seems like something is missing from your logs.  Have you looked at the requests?  Is the bucket configured properly for cors requests?

Comment: Note that this does seem like a CORS issue to me, which is why I have asked about the CORS settings in the bucket.

Comment: Bucket is being used by other customers with no problem.  I have the signature request saved, but I didn't post it because it was successful.  I stupidly didn't save OPTIONS request to the bucket.  It was just a request part...there was no response at all.

Comment: If there was no response at all, there is likely a network issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your log message indicates that a response was in fact received, but it was completely empty.  However, in your comments, you have indicated that no response was received at all.  If that is true, then there are network issues.  If the latter is true, then something client-side is interfering with the response, perhaps a browser extension.

Comment: I turned on logging in S3 and am seeing lots of these: `6b41ffb3e70fae8c6b91753f9a1a6229509bf9104aaa4bdf1b128fdd6e9efebe <url removed> [18/Sep/2013:12:09:21 +0000] <ip removed> - 95942C68A7C0E7D4 REST.OPTIONS.PREFLIGHT 71/171871/ "OPTIONS /71/171871/ HTTP/1.1" 400 BadRequest 271 - 3 - "-" "Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery" -`

Comment: Does the redacted IP address point to your customer's local/controlled server?

Comment: The ip was for the customer.  The url was my cnamed S3 URL...actually I guess that is the bucket.  It was files.myurl.com.  Some of the others have different parts instead of "Microsoft Office Protocol Discovery".  I also see "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601" and "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider Protocol Discovery"

Comment: I occasionally get remote access to computers with this problem.  Let me know if there is something I should look for.  I was just on one where it didn't work in Chrome, but worked in IE.  I'm pretty sure it was IE10.  Chrome had the dev tools disabled, so I couldn't see much.  These are always school computers, so I can't install anything and are generally very locked down.

Comment: All I can think of is an overly aggressive firewall or network appliance filtering the traffic.

Comment: Yea, it looks like the AJAX request is not getting through. I guess because it's cross domain? My bucket is cnamed to a subdomain that is the same as the site. Is that still cross domain?  I found the S3 log entry that was successful and it was IE7, so iFrame method. I didn't find anything in the S3 logs for the failed one I did today.  Any chance of having some sort of fallback to iFrame when ajax doesn't work regardless of browser?

Comment: I can't really think of a reason why you would want to fall back to an iframe targeted form submit on a modern browser.  If something at the customer site is blocking these ajax requests, then that will need to be addressed.  If such a restriction exists, it is quite odd.  Besides, you lose a lot by moving away from XHR, such as progress bars, chunking, etc.  If you are sure the XHR request is not being sent, I'd try to get to the bottom of that.

Comment: I put together a quick test page of a cross domain ajax request to a text file on S3.  Didn't work at customers site.  They are blocked somehow, although regular ajax is fine.  I'm going to have to come up with a solution other then fixing their network.  Anyway I can use the autoRetry callback to switch methods if the first attempt fails?

Comment: What do you mean by "switch methods"?

Comment: Switch to iframe method instead of cross domain ajax.

Comment: There isn't currently a way to do that, short of monkey patching the existing code.  I haven't received such a request, until now.

Comment: Are you sure the CORS configuration is correct in the bucket?

Comment: Please post the CORS XML by editing your question.  You can redact the client's host/IP.  My initial suspicion was improper CORS configuration, and that still seems to be the case.  Most likely, the CORS XML in your bucket is not correct for this client, and, as a result, the browser is blocking the response after the preflight (OPTIONS) fails and not sending the underlying request.  You can verify by looking at the network tab in Chrome, for example.

Comment: Posted.  Wouldn't all Chromes have the issue then? It seems to be specific instances.

Comment: Seems ok to me.  Could be a browser extension then?  Hard to say without taking a closer look myself.  What are you seeing in the network tab?

Comment: I'll check the network tab next time I get access to someone having this issue.  Would you want to take a look yourself?  I could contact you next time I have someone willing to let me in.

Comment: Perhaps.  I'll only be available to check it out during business hours.

Comment: That's fine. These customers are only available then.  How can I contact you?

Comment: Please reply to the last email you received from us.

Comment: Got this from a network engineer at one of the locations that is having the issue: "We found that our layer 7 firewall is classifying the upload as BitTorrent when doing the upload that of course we block for security reasons."  I know, I know...it's silly they are blocking it.  The problem is most locations won't know how to fix this.  I would still love to be able to switch to iFrame mode if the upload failed on the first attempt.

Comment: @MattCurry I'd love to discuss this in some more detail in the Github project's issue tracker.  Can you open a request there?  https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

Super old question, but OP comments that the bucket name contains a `.`, which is likely related to the same issue as [here](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/issues/23):

When bucket names contain a dot, the endpoint needs to be:

`s3-{region}.amazonaws.com/{bucket-name}`

Without dots, the following works:

`{bucket-name}.s3.amazonaws.com`