# S3 chunked uploads not (always) working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

We recently started using fineuploader. Testing different browsers on different platforms all worked as expected. But test in Chrome (V31+) with chunking enabled failed (on most of our test files). We tested Chrome on Windows Vista, 7 and 8.1. All with the same result.

We can reproduce the problem. Just upload a large file with Chrome (v30+) and it fails. With chunking false it will upload.

When we try the S3 upload example @findeuploader.com we get the same results.

We are using fineuploader 4.1.0

**Chrome javascript console output**

```
XHR finished loading: "myServer/upload/sign".
[FineUploader 4.1.0] Sending part 1 of 3 for file ID 0 - abc.mp4 (5242880 bytes)
[FineUploader 4.1.0] Received response status 0 with body:
[FineUploader 4.1.0] Received response status 0 with body:
[FineUploader 4.1.0] Received response status 0 with body:
[FineUploader 4.1.0] Upload attempt for file ID 0 to S3 is complete
[FineUploader 4.1.0] 'error' is not a valid property on the server response. 
Upload ready
PUT myS3/abc.mp4?par… 2cYTjCx96l273jY.1gqFFifuLauX19eaQ.v_ixHtUIPcT7YK4jgv3Fwe12njmKYlP9FbRd9fx_  myS3/abc.mp4?partNumber…YTjCx96l273jY.1gqFFifuLauX19eaQ.v_ixHtUIPcT7YK4jgv3Fwe12njmKYlP9FbRd9fx_
```

**Network console output**

```
sign POST 200 application/json
abc.mp4?uploads OPTIONS 200 text/plain
abc.mp4?uploads POST 200 text/xml
sign POST 200 application/json
abc.mp4?partNumber=1&uploadId=KtGZbUYtRz8qD1TpzRKq20wX8PM8wMb0ZIUAdmt_U5q2mZ3Y8z2UAR2cYTjCx96l273jY.1gqFFifuLauX19eaQ.v_ixHtUIPcT7YK4jgv3Fwe12njmKYlP9FbRd9fx_ OPTIONS 200 text/plain
abc.mp4?partNumber=1&uploadId=KtGZbUYtRz8qD1TpzRKq20wX8PM8wMb0ZIUAdmt_U5q2mZ3Y8z2UAR2cYTjCx96l273jY.1gqFFifuLauX19eaQ.v_ixHtUIPcT7YK4jgv3Fwe12njmKYlP9FbRd9fx_ PUT (failed) Pending Other
```

**Headers from failing PUT**

```
Request URL: myS3/abc.mp4?partNumber=1&uploadId=uETmRvNAAROHscyF6rVikoJKb6ypHkB2yeepaddTLPVjSOwAu0hh2Hh9l59NQogvuB0uWGmUSy66bBh9SX6Vdnwttte8gEp2V4tozKcqBJfCz6uGqEu6EQUZc_yQklds

Request Headers
PUT myS3/abc.mp4?partNumber=1&uploadId=uETmRvNAAROHscyF6rVikoJKb6ypHkB2yeepaddTLPVjSOwAu0hh2Hh9l59NQogvuB0uWGmUSy66bBh9SX6Vdnwttte8gEp2V4tozKcqBJfCz6uGqEu6EQUZc_yQklds HTTP/1.1
Authorization: AWS myKey
Referer: myServer/test3
Origin:myServer
x-amz-date: Tue, 03 Dec 2013 19:55:30 GMT
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Content-Type:

Query String Parameters
partNumber=1&uploadId=uETmRvNAAROHscyF6rVikoJKb6ypHkB2yeepaddTLPVjSOwAu0hh2Hh9l59NQogvuB0uWGmUSy66bBh9SX6Vdnwttte8gEp2V4tozKcqBJfCz6uGqEu6EQUZc_yQklds
```

**CORS Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

So the first PUT fails in Chrome but i have no clue why.

Strange thing is, 2 of our (30+) test files (400M+ videos) upload without any problem.

Anyone any ideas or maybe a clue where how to debug this issue?

Comment: Looking into this. I'm not able to reproduce the issue on Chrome 32.0.1700.19 beta on either the Fineuploader.com site or locally on my development server. Do you have any relevant code you'd be willing to share? Client- or server-side would be useful.

Comment: Are you getting any response from the PUT request? Also, is your bucket's CORS configuration set up properly? Mind sharing that as well, feel free to redact any IP addresses?

Comment: We are just testing the s3 demo script. Client same as the code running on fineuploader.com. Serverside we are using the demo php code.

Comment: The PUT fails directly (36ms) with status Pending.

Answer (score 0):

Your log message indicates that a response was received, but it was completely empty and had a status code of `0`.

`[FineUploader 4.1.0] Received response status 0 with body:`

If that is true, then there are network issues.

Also, ensure that there are no extensions (HTTPS Everywhere and Adblock, for example) fiddling with the network traffic.

Comment: Yup, i noticed that. But wouldn't we have this problem also in the other browsers? We test lots of browsers and versions on different machines and only Chrome has trouble with chunking enabled.

Comment: Maybe, depending on the network at the time you tried and potential browser extensions. In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561724/fine-uploader-post-to-s3-returns-response-code-0?rq=1) (which is very similar to yours) the asker narrowed it down to a firewall issue. Now, I realize it is not browser specific, but the fact that your response's status is 0 and has no body indicates that it must be network issues.

Comment: Well maybe your right, i will try again tommorow from dmz and other locations.

Comment: one more question

    [FineUploader 4.1.0] Received response status 0 with body:

I assume this is about the PUT request.

Comment: Yes. According to your console your response status was 0 and the body was empty. A good response will have a status and a body (a _correct_ response would have a status of 200 and more information in the body). In the question I linked someone was having that same issue and it was down to network issues (see the last comments on Ray's answer). Is it still not working for you?

Comment: We have been testing from different location, with and without firewall's, different access providers. But the problem is consistent. We looked at the S3 logs and we notice with uploads gone wrong httpstatus '400' with error message 'IncompleteBody'

Comment: Very interesting. Working on reproducing. According to [Amazon's docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) this error means: "You did not provide the number of bytes specified by the Content-Length HTTP header". I'll look into why Fine Uploader would not be specifying this header.

Comment: Great. We have been testing somemore. This is waht we found. The problem only seems to occur in Chrome (all test devices run latest V31.0.16..). We use a fixed set of videos for upload testing. A few of these video's would upload. We tried a large set of random file's with non standard filenames and different extension. Here we find the same problem. Most wouldn't upload, some would. But we cannot find a pattern. We even looked at the video's metadata. But when a file fails to upload it fails every time.

Comment: Done more testing. Firebug console gives an error/warning with every chunk. It's ignoring these warnings so upload goes without a problem. I don't think it's related to the Chrome issue. But the XML error message is coming from S3: <Error><Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code><Message>The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message><ResourceType>PART</ResourceType><Method>GET</Method><RequestId>long#</RequestId><HostId>londer#</HostId></Error>.

Comment: Thanks for following up, @RolfMeijer. Are you sure your user has correct permissions for the S3 bucket, and the bucket's policy document is correct?

Comment: Thanks for your response. But if the user permissions where incorrect upload would be impossible in all browsers.

Comment: We set the CORS permissions as loose as possible. (See question). The user is setup same as the fineuplaoder s3 blog example. We don't have any bucket policies set.

Comment: Still not able to reproduce. Do you have a web app that we could use to try to test and recreate?